# iOS/iPadOS 17.1 has new issue with QR scanning

Tags: avfoundation, qr-code, scanning, ios17

After upgrading to iOS 17.1, I can't scan `some` QR codes. The same codes can be scanned correctly with earlier versions of iOS. In details:

- iOS 17.0 and earlier:

  [image: Works well]
- iPadOS 17.1:

  [image: Something goes wrong]
- Sample project code:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, 
                    didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], 
                    from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    guard let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first,
          let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { 
        return 
    }

    guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else {
        foundButInvalid()
        return
    }
    found(code: stringValue)
}
```

- Sample QR code

  [image: Japanese text]
- All assets:
  [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rtuUfetaXUx-atnRjYO77V6qvkORaSWO/view?pli=1)

P.S: It's easy to see the issue with the built-in Camera app: With QR code scanning option enabled, iOS Camera app can regconize the QR with iOS 17.0, but 17.1

[image: iOS 16.4.1]
[image: iPadOS 17.1]

Comment: Did you found solution, I have the same problem, and note that the QR scanning is work normal in iOS 17.2 beta.

Comment: @goat_herd I can't seem to find a way to inject anything (encoding) to the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`. Anyway, it's good to know that Apple fixes the issue in the newest beta version. Cheers!